# Moved ghosted files in 14 hive - now get 404

Tags: ghosting

I've got a feature deploying a module containing a page layout file, which it 'places' in /_catalogs/masterpage/ using GhostableInLibrary. (So it doesn't actually go in the catalog, it stays in the 14 hive.)

This worked fine.

I've since renamed my feature, project etc., and redeployed, so the actual physical file is now in a different place in the 14 hive.

I now get the following when SharePoint tries to read the file:

```
Relying on fallback logic in VghostPageManager::getGhostDocument() for document:
'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template
\Features\Old.Project.Name_OldFeatureName\ModuleName\FileName.aspx'
```

followed by similar lines for the 12 and 60 hives.

Since I've redeployed the feature, I would've expected SharePoint to 'overwrite' the reference in the catalog, but this doesn't seem to have happened.

How can I tell SharePoint to update its reference to this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to de-activate the feature, delete the file from the masterpage gallery, then re-activate the feature

Comment: I've tried this, but I get the error "This item cannot be deleted because it is still referenced by other pages"

Comment: In that case, you'll also need to work out which pages are referencing the page layout and either delete them first or change the page layout to a different one.