# Why is my MySite looking at hive 60 for its files?

Tags: deployment, 404, hive

404: "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\60\Template\SiteTemplates\CUSTOMMYSITE\default.aspx"

It was working perfectly fine until I got the above after one deployment, I went back to a slightly older solution and the same, I can't seem to find the error.

I believe 60 is to do with SQL Server 2000 Desktop Engine (Windows) (WMSDE) but why is my sharepoint suddenly looking there.

The only thing I did was to use feature stapling to create a MyContent page which succeeded but going back to the MySite is now not possible. All other site collections work correctly.

The only new code that was run is below:

```
string masterPageUrl = "/_catalog/masterpage/MyContentCustom.master";
currentWeb.CustomMasterUrl = masterPageUrl;
currentWeb.MasterUrl = masterPageUrl;
```

[update] I forgot the url for the site collection which stopped the 404 in the above code for the master page, however I still don't understand why it is falling back to the 60 folder, can anyone explain this behavior?

[update] This appears from the face of it to be a fallback mechanism for errors that could of arisen from an upgrade and just part of 2010 trying not to error? I can't seem to confirm this however. (I have +1 the posts which are in the right direction but no definitive answer as yet of this behavior although it seems linked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I gave points for work trying to figure this out and the helpful ones, however the answer is there is an internal automatic fallback to the old hive 60 when a file can't be found straight OOTB.

I tested this by watching the IO errors for master templates when putting in wrong files in the ULS and either the code was left in by accident or by design but it definitely falls back for files to the old install.

This I feel could result in unintended behavior on a SharePoint system which has received an upgrade, but it's there, I am aware of the behavior now and have to live with it.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if this has anything to do with it.... I thought that 60 was for  SPS 2003 and WSS 2.0 files. It looks like you had a problem upgrading.

> Windows SharePoint Services uses a different strategy for upgrading a
>   page depending on whether or not it has been customized (unghosted).
>
> Windows SharePoint Services tracks whether a Web site was created
>   through a Windows SharePoint Services 2.0 (\web server extensions\60)
>   or Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 (\web server extensions\12) site
>   definition. A Web site can be upgraded by virtue of having an update
>   definition that translates front-end site definition files that have
>   not been customized. After the upgrade process, any references to
>   uncustomized front-end files are mapped from the \web server
>   extensions\60 directory to \Web server extensions\12.
>
> Not every Web site is upgraded from \60 to \12 at the time of initial
>   upgrade. Any existing site definitions that do not have upgrade paths
>   will still function, but continue to point to their \60 pages. Also, a
>   Web site that is updated from \60 to \12 may still have Windows
>   SharePoint Services 2.0 pages (in other words, no master page, no Web
>   Part manager) that have been customized and thereby stored in the
>   database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms456521(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Never had anything but 2010 on this hyper-v, but I am sure 60 is MSSQL windows desktop (Which was possibly extended for 2003? I don't know). However it may be similar in 2010 ie it is looking for an upgrade path on a 404 presuming it was upgraded from an earlier version of sharepoint. Wish I knew for sure but it may be the reason.

Comment: If you look at your 12Hive or 14Hive and see if 60 Hive exisists. If it does then look to see what files are there. I do too find that a very odd behaviour, if you say is correct that its only 2010 on your hyper-v so shouldnt have any corrolation to hive 60. Unless you have some underlying code that references to 60Hive.. I pressume that you used to have 2003?

Comment: No, this is a fresh solution and has never had anything to do with anything bar 2010, all I can think of is it must be a fall back mechanism in 2010 when it thinks it "may be an upgrade".

Comment: I would think so too, but its just very strange behavior to fall back as i havent heard or experienced that as it should do unless there has been an upgrade which in your case isnt!! So it shouldnt be referencing to 60hive as it wouldnt know about it as its only to do with SPS 2003 and WSS 2.0 files

Comment: I dont suppose this has somthing to do with your issue? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26870/moved-ghosted-files-in-14-hive-now-get-404

Comment: No, similar but I don't get a fallback error if I did I wouldn't open this question just blog about it *sadface* the error is a IO error file not found in the ULS resulting in a 404 front end. I'm stumped and can just presume it is related.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4779/discussion-between-hugh-wood-and-almostsharepointmaster)

Answer (score 1):

60 hive is where WSS 2.0 or SPS 2003 files were stored. Did you upgrade to 2007/WSS 3.0 on the same machine or box?

Comment: Nope, fresh install sharepoint 2010 with all the latest software and updates, and when a master page 404 it trys to look at 60, this is as far as I have got.